# identical lists as pandas rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas as mentioned below where list elements in column info is same as unique file in column id:

```
id   text         info
1    great        ['son','daughter']
1    excellent    ['son','daughter']
2    nice         ['father','mother','brother']
2    good         ['father','mother','brother']
2    bad          ['father','mother','brother']
3    awesome       nan
4    superb       ['grandson']
```

All I want to get list elements as row for each file, like:

```
id   text         info
1    great        son
1    excellent    daughter
2    nice         father
2    good         mother
2    bad          brother
3    awesome      nan
4    superb       grandson
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70351077/7964527

Answer (score 2):

You can drop duplicate on `id`, explode the `info` column and assign the values back:

```
df['info'] = df.loc[~df['id'].duplicated(), 'info'].explode().values
```

Output:

```
   id       text      info
0   1      great       son
1   1  excellent  daughter
2   2       nice    father
3   2       good    mother
4   2        bad   brother
5   3    awesome       NaN
6   4     superb  grandson
```